# How do I render image component based on the image uri inside an array in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, components

I have an array of image URI.

> ["file:///data/user/0/com.app.outlet/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/22536474236950.png","file:///data/user/0/com.app.outlet/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/22583225016770.png"]

I want to render the image component based on the length of the array and show and show all the images. How can I do it in react native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will help you:

```
var array =   ["file:///data/user/0/com.app.outlet/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/22536474236950.png","file:///data/user/0/com.app.outlet/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/22583225016770.png"]
    
   array.map((x)=>{
     return(<Image source={x || whatever you want } style={{xx:"xx"}} />)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have image in array you can use map function and display in image component

```
data = ['a.png',b.png']

data.map((item,index)=>{<Image src={item.data })
```

like that it is just demo example